# Filter simultaneous criteria using grep

Tags: filter, grep

I need to create a filter that can filter out any string that:

- Is less than 3 characters
- Contains numbers or symbols (i.e. anything that is not an item in the Latin alphabet)

Example:
INPUT FILE:

```
5-hydroxy-3-methylglutaryl-coenzyme_a_reductase
5-hydroxytryptamine
a
a
a
aa
abaca
abo_antibodies
abradant
abrasive
```

OUTPUT FILE:

```
abaca
abradant
abrasive
```

I have been looking at grep options:

```
grep -v [itemtoremove] [inputfile] > [outputfile]
```

which seems to do the trick. However, it only removes each item individually, meaning that to remove everything that I need from the file, I would have to continuously run this script.

Does anyone have a solution so that I can filter everything necessary with one grep (or other more efficient command line)?

***UPDATED QUESTION***

Below there have been several great solutions that solve the problem.

However, I would like to apply the same to the an input file that has 4 tab-separated columns.

I have been tried the following modification:

```
grep '^[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]-n$' input
```

The input is now the following:

```
a-n such_as-handheld-n  6.4623  A
abaca-n such_as-head-n  2.5586  A
abo_antibodies-n    such_as-headphone-n 8.0794  A
abrasive-n  such_as-healthcare-n    5.2845  A
function-n  such_as-hearing-n   9.5367  A
```

where we want the following output:

```
abaca-n such_as-head-n  2.5586  A
abrasive-n  such_as-healthcare-n    5.2845  A
function-n  such_as-hearing-n   9.5367  A
```

Can someone show me where I am going wrong with the modified grep?
It outputs me a blank file.
Thanks!

Comment: Why `abradant` was excluded from output?

Comment: Human error: check edit in example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part of the question, the following should work with almost any grep.

```
grep '^[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]*$' infile
```

For the 'Upgraded Question', the following produces the specified output from the specified input (making some assumptions about the whitespace as presented in my browser).

```
grep '^[a-z-][a-z-][a-z-][a-z-]*-n  [a-z_-]*-n  [0-9]\.[0-9]*   [A-Z]$' infile
```

This regular expression includes exactly two whitespace characters, which are tabs.

Since the specified input now contains hyphens and underscores that are desired in the output, the above takes a simple approach to handling the hyphens and underscores.  I made some guesses about how you wanted the third and fourth columns treated.

It is an interesting coincidence that:

- all the lines you want have the first column items ending in '-n'xcompile
- ditto the second column items starting with 'such_as-'
- those are the only places underscores or hyphens are specified

So perhaps you want the expression to look more like this:

```
grep '^[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]*-n  such_as-[a-z]*  [0-9]\.[0-9]*   [A-Z]$' input
```

And now I notice other coincidences, like the recurrence of 'hea' as the start of the word following 'such_as-'.  But perhaps this is enough for now?

Comment: If I wanted to apply this grep on only the 1st of 4 tab-separated columns. How can I modify this command to produced the desired result?

Comment: Question has been revised above with the fully-detailed question.

Answer (score 2):

This works :

```
egrep  -v "[^a-zA-Z]" infile | egrep "[a-zA-Z]{3,}" > outfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `perl` flavour of regex, use characters from `[[:alpha:]]` group and anchor the match to begin and end of line with `^` and `$`:

```
grep -P '^[[:alpha:]]{3,}$' infile
```

It yields:

```
abaca
abradant
abrasive
```